# Android: make a view overlap other views on hover

Tags: android, animation

I have a layout looking like this:

```
<ListView>
<LinearLayout><ImageView><ImageView>...</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout><ImageView><ImageView>...</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout><ImageView><ImageView>...</LinearLayout>
....
</ListView>
```

I want each ImageView to expand when it receivs a hover event, so it would overlap other views a little bit (like Reef2 on the screenshot): [image]

I use the following code to achieve this effect:

```
view.bringToFront();
view.animate().scaleX(1.3f).scaleY(1.3f);
```

But it looks like this instead (the expanded view is beyond other views): [image]

Is there any way to make the scaled view overlap it's neighbours?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [setClipChildren](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setClipChildren%28boolean%29) to false on the parent(s) of your ImageView(s), i.e. each LinearLayout.

Side note: all of those LinearLayouts aren't going to perform very well especially if you are using nested weights to space them in a grid, perhaps you should check out [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)